# Client&Server program issue

Tags: c, sockets

I'm building a client&server program. Below it is the code referred to the socket in the main function on the server side:

```
   listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

   bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

   listen(listenfd, 10);
   pthread_t thread[10];
   while(1)
   {
       connfd[i] = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
       //I WANT TO GET THE IP ADDRESS HERE
       if( pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, listener, NULL ) != 0 )
       {
           printf("Cannot create thread , exiting \n ");
           exit(-1);
       }
       i++;
   }
```

and the thread is as follows:

```
void * listener( void * temp_pt )
{
    int connfdLocal=connfd[i];
    while ( (n = read(connfdLocal, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
    {
        printf("TESTING LISTENER");         
        write(connfdLocal, "TEST", strlen("TEST"));     
    }

    if(n <= 0)
    {
        printf("\n Connection lost \n");
        close(connfdLocal);
        return 0;
    } 

}
```

Well, I have 3 questions:

1. For some reason the thread does not print "TESTING LISTENER" until the connection with the client is closed, I have to close the connection on the client side. Likewise, it is not until I close the connection on the server that string "TEST" is sent to the client. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?
2. Is there any way I can get the ip address of the client after the connection is established? Just where I typed "I WANT THE GET THE IP ADDRESS HERE"
3. Can someone explain to me how is it that 'n' immediately turn to 0 when the socket is closed on the client side? I thought the read function was only run once and the n value was only set once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely happens because of buffering. So the `printf` really does get called but the text sits in the `stdio` buffer. Try:

```
printf("TESTING LISTENER\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Same goes for the client.

> Is there any way I can get the ip address of the client

You need the function `getpeername(2)`.

> I thought the read function was only run once and the n value was only
>   set once

It's the number of bytes received at each call. It's not a fixed value.

Comment: thank you, i worked for "TESTING LISTENER", however "TEST" is still not sent to the client until the serveris closed, I don't know how to fflush "connfdLocal". The client side is actually programmed in java, should I add a fflush there?

Comment: regarding the 3rd question what I meant is that I think the function read should only be run once when a client connects to the server, however it seems to be set to a negative value right after the client closes the socket.

Comment: @user2071976 No, it should be run continously until 0 or -1 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason the thread does not print "TESTING LISTENER" until the connection with the client is closed, I have to close the connection on the client side. Likewise, it is not until I close the connection on the server that string "TEST" is sent to the client. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

I will need few more info:

1. How is recvBuff defined?
2. Is it defined on heap or on stack?
3. Are you checking this connection on local computer or remote?
4. Have you checked error code on client side when it writes to server?
5. Have you checked Firewall Settings?

> Is there any way I can get the ip address of the client after the connection is established? Just where I typed "I WANT THE GET THE IP ADDRESS HERE"

Yes you can. Just declare and pass "struct sockaddr&" in accept parameter.

```
struct sockaddr cli_addr; 
connfd[i] = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));
char *connected_ip = inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr); //Client Ip Address
int port = ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port); //Client's Port
```

> Can someone explain to me how is it that 'n' immediately turn to 0 when the socket is closed on the client side? I thought the read function was only run once and the n value was only set once.

Its the total bytes received from client. It turns zero because socket is closed from remote end. What to read when there is no source to read from rite...